# What does this undocumented solid red LED (Intel 2.5G LAN) on the RJ45 connection mean?

Tags: ethernet, led, rj-45

On a Gigabyte Aorus X570S PRO AX board the RJ45 LAN Port is documented with[image]

Here's what I observe. Note the *red* speed LED. Both are solid on, the amber Activity LED flickers only momentarily since there is not much traffic. The switch it is connected to can only provide 1Gbit/s. Changing ports or cables has no effect.

[image: Red (NO, not amber) LED]

The board's BIOS has the LAN port enabled, but reports "Link Status: disconnected". Ubuntu recognizes the NIC as an `igc`. Other Gigabyte docs refer to the LAN as "Intel 2.5GbE LAN" and "Intel(R) Ethernet Controller(3) I225-V".
**What is the red LED signaling?**

**EDIT:** Board is OK. Ubuntu sees the NIC and can use it. FreeBSD requires `igc` driver.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill "What is the red LED signaling?"

Comment: @Jens I fixed the title to actual ask a question. “RJ45 Speed LED shows undocumented solid red (Intel 2.5G LAN)” is just a statement.

Answer (score 2):

Humans sometimes process colors differently. I see an orange light in your picture, indicating that the link is at 1Gbps per your documentation. The activity light won't tell you much if the OS hasn't brought the NIC up, but the NIC does see the switch, and appears to have autonegotiated its speed/duplex correctly.

If you want to test that the port functions independent of your freebsd issue, try booting from an ubuntu liveCD, and see if you can see the nic there. Ubuntu supports most common NICs out-of-box.

Comment: The LED is red, there's no doubt. The image does not do the human-perceived colors justice.  Even the BIOS says link status disconnected, from which I conclude that it can detect link status properly, but for some reason does not. Maybe the PHY reports a failed self-test this way? I'll try Ubuntu as suggested.

Comment: @Jens I must admit when I look at that I also see a deep orange, but as you say, the image doesn’t necessarily represent what you see (camera sensor and my screen obviously are variables here), and the behaviour you’re experiencing obviously doesn’t align with it merely being a odd choice of orange on the engineering side. Do you have a 2.5Gb device that can be connected, just for comparison’s sake, and a second cable that could be connected to rule out wiring?

Comment: @FreelancerJ I've tested several wires, LED is always red. Triple color LEDs are common. If you look closely, you can even see that the red comes from a slightly different origin (more to the left) than the amber (more in the middle). I'm not color blind and would bet my life the LED is red. It's not a slight difference in hue. It's obvious. Anyway, I can report that Ubuntu does probe the NIC properly and has IP connectivity. FreeBSD needs 13-STABLE or later with the `igc` driver. I'm happy to report that the board is not faulty, but still don't know what the red speed indicates.

Comment: @Jens "I can report that Ubuntu does probe the NIC properly and has IP connectivity." – So… what color is the LED when the NIC works?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Solid red.

Comment: @Jens It's *plausible* the technical writer responsible for the manual saw orange; or a photo where it looked orange (like in your first photo). Or just a specification where the part was with an orange LED, but then there was shortage or whatever and they used an equivalent part with a red LED.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Indeed, or maybe someone at the factory inserted the wrong spool of LEDs in the machine. It would be interesting if other people with the PRO AX board see different colors, depending on switch capabilities.

Comment: @Jens yes absolutely not doubting you more just commenting on what it appears like on my screen. I’m curious if it’ll look more red in the morning when night shift is off. Super glad it’s not faulty. And good eyes, I’ve never noticed the offsets before but just looked at my main switch and it’s indicators are all like that too. What has been seen can not be unseen 

Comment: Perhaps the light should be orange, and that it would now fail strict quality checking.